# How to open all the closed XML tags in one shot?

Tags: xml, notepad++, replace

I have a huge XML with all the tags closed like `<XXXXXX/>` and i am looking for a solution to open all the closed tags at a time like `<XXXXXX> </XXXXXX>` using Notepad++. Any answers could help me in great.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Notepad++'s RegEx search and replace options (which is why this was a comment), but, if it is available, something like Search:`<([^<>/]+)/>` and Replace:`<\1></\1>` should do it.

Comment: Mark,really thanks for the help.It worked like champ!!! You saved my time...Thanks once again...

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept it by clicking on the tick on the left.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean that the tags are collapsed, then:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Will expand them all. See this and other neat tricks at the [keyboard shortcuts page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)

Comment: Based upon the question title only I was going to mention NumPad <kbd>*</kbd> is the default Windows keystroke to expand sub-entries in TreeViews.

Comment: Does that apply to Notepad++?